# jQuery to Find Previous TR until it reaches a TD contains DATA

Tags: javascript, jquery

In short, the problem I'm facing is not being able to keep skipping previous TR until I reach to the TD with class start-timecode with no empty value.

Here is actual code that works fine if there is no empty TD of timecode:
https://jsfiddle.net/jLx1sfx8/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {   
  $('#check').click(function(e) {
    var activeExists = $('#caption-table .active-narrative').length;
    if (activeExists > 0) {
      var totalRows = $('#caption-table tr').length;
      var startTimeThisRange = $('.active-narrative .start-timecode').text();
      var startTimeNextRange = $('.active-narrative').closest('tr').prev().find('.start-timecode').text();
      alert(startTimeNextRange);
    }
  });     
});
```

But, when there is an empty TD of timecode in previous row then it doesn't work to get its start-timecode. As you can see here.
https://jsfiddle.net/jLx1sfx8/5/

**RESULT NEED:**
I want jQuery to keep skipping previous rows until it reaches to the TD contains start-timecode which have the data.

Note: I tried `:empty`, `:has`, untilAll etc but somehow couldn't achieve it or most probably I'm exactly not sure about exact syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `while` loop to check the `tr`s in order:

https://jsfiddle.net/62eo08tt/

```
  $('#check').click(function(e) {
    var activeExists = $('#caption-table .active-narrative').length;

    if (activeExists > 0) {
      var totalRows = $('#caption-table tr').length;
      var startTimeThisRange = $('.active-narrative .start-timecode').text();

      var $prevTr = $('.active-narrative').closest('tr').prev();
      while ($prevTr.length && $.trim($prevTr.find('.start-timecode').text()) == '') {
        $prevTr = $prevTr.prev();
      }

      var startTimeNextRange = $prevTr.find('.start-timecode').text();
      alert(startTimeNextRange);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with one deliciously long jQuery chain and *no intermediate assignments* :

```
var startTimeNextRange = $('.active-narrative')
.closest('tr') // active-narrative's table row
.prevAll() // all previous TRs (in same tbody)
.find('.start-timecode') // Within those TRs find all SPANs with class="start-timecode"
.filter(function() { // filter to eliminate empty SPANs
    return !!this.innerText; // return `false` for empty SPANs, `true` for populated SPANs
})
.eq(-1) // select the last populated SPAN.
.text(); // grab its text

if(startTimeNextRange) { // need test here because `startTimeNextRange` will be falsy if no qualifying SPANs were found.
    alert(startTimeNextRange);
} else {
    alert('not found');
}
```

**[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/8muzpg85/1/)**